# C# Asp.net Convert.toDateTime(datevalue) gives error with different cultureinfo need datepattern look like  5/1/2012 12:00:00 AM

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, datetime, datetime-format

In my **Asp.net** Website i have two **textboxes** (txtstartdate, txtenddate) applied **JQquery Datepicker** which popups gives date in format ("**05/24/2012**"). Work fine for cultureInfo("**en-US**"), when i change to ("**de**") ie German its give error **"System.FormatException: String was not recognized as a valid DateTime."**.
In my code behind file i am writing this code

```
 string sDate = txtstartdate.Text;  //  05/01/2012 (debugging gives this values)
 string eDate = txtenddate.Text;    //   05/24/2012 (debugging gives this values)

 DateTime startdate = Convert.ToDateTime(sDate); //  5/1/2012 12:00:00 AM
 DateTime enddate = Convert.ToDateTime(eDate);   //  5/24/2012 12:00:00 AM
```

My requirement is **datetime** variable must give date of format   **5/1/2012 12:00:00 AM** whatever be the cultureinfo set doesnt matter to the date.So that i can execute **select query** in **MsSql Server** existing table having column datatype **Datetime** with data (5/1/2012 12:00:00 AM) formart

After Changing the **CultureInfo** (from Masterpage dropdownlist) **Englsih to German** gives error
Have tried this but not working

```
 DateTime startdate = DateTime.ParseExact(sDate, "M/d/yyyy", null); 
 //tried also "MM/dd/yyyy"
```

**Note:** Set any cultileinfo, but the datetime pattern alwayz be 5/1/2012 12:00:00 AM ie `en-US` culture

Answer (score 1):

You could try using `"MM/dd/yyyy"` as your format string when you call `ParseExact`, assuming that you're sure the input will always be in that format.

Alternatively, try using `Convert.ToDateTime(yourString, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)` instead.

Comment: as u said have used Convert.ToDateTime(yourString, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture) this give  out put 01.05.2012 00:00:00
which create error

Comment: @LukeH "MM/dd/yyy" won't work in "de" culture, because the slashes represent a culture-specific date separator, which is period in Germany.  However using CultureInfo.InvariantCulture (your second suggestion) will of course work.

Comment: @Satinder singh - "this give out put 01.05.2012 00:00:00" - no, the output is a DateTime instance, which is a binary representation of a date/time.  Of course when you then try to format that date/time using a German culture, you'll get the German format your seeing by default, unless you explicitly specify a different format string and/or culture.

Comment: @joe: when i bedug i get this value "01.05.2012 00:00:00" for de as datetime variable.
and in my mssql values stored in 5/1/2012 12:00:00 AM formart. so i can't execute select query for german formart.

Comment: @Satinder, when you debug, the binary DateTime will be displayed using the current culture, German in your case.  For MySql, you should ideally use a parametrized query; or failing that, simply format the DateTime using the format and culture expected by the db = e.g. `DateTime.ToString("M/d/yyyy hh:mm:ss tt", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)`

Comment: @Joe: The date separator can be a literal if necessary, rather than being culture-dependent. For example, *"MM'/'dd'/'yyyy"* will always use `/` regardless of the culture.

Comment: @LukeH, yes it can, but my point is that your's isn't a literal, it's a culture-specific separator.

Comment: @Joe , luke _ still waiting for good answer, otherwise have to change my datatime to string and depend on condition ie eu,de,fr make the string datepatern.

Answer (score 0):

I think in this case you have to set the [altFormat](http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Datepicker#option-altFormat) of your calendar to the format used by SQL server.  Then, you can use a hidden field to store the altDate for each of your date pickers.  When you submit, the value of the [altField](http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Datepicker#option-altField), in the correct format would be sent to your server instead of the culture-specific value that's displayed to the user.

Comment: datetime format automaticaly set as per selected current cultureinfo. their may be many culture ie(german,frnce,Us) all i need always default En-us format datetime

Comment: Right. So you can set the altFormat to en-us format, but the text box that the calendar is bound to will display in user's local format.

Comment: thnx for reply, well no issue with what format is display in textbox. my problem comes when i try to convert that textvalue to datetime using **convert.toDatetime(txtvalue)**  gives error when i select german. Is their any universal format which supports all the cultureinfo

Comment: Every culture can have a different culture info so there is no universal format. Unfortunately, getting a date in the correct format from a web page is not very straight forward. What value are you getting when you take the date from the altField instead of txtValue?